# Decision tree to check 2 rectangles

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees, decision-problem

Given two disjoint rectangles $(a,b]\times (c,d]$ and $(e,f]\times (g,h]$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ how can I check with a decision tree of least depth if a given point $(x,y)$ lies within the union of the rectangles?

I think that I need 4 decisions to check if $x$ is within $(\min(a,e),\max(b,f)]$ and if $y$ is within $(\min(c,g),\max(d,h)]$. However I am stuck afterwards, as we don't know how exactly the rectangles are positioned (they could overlap in $x$ or $y$ coordinates and we don't know which of them is to the 'left' and which to the 'right').

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If no preprocessing of the rectangles is allowed, in the worst case you need $8$ comparisons, full stop. That's because there are $8$ independent coordinates and the answer depends on them.

---

If preprocessing is allowed, you can determine a vertical or horizontal line by one of the sides that separates the two rectangles. After comparing to this line, you need additional $3$ or $4$ comparisons to check insideness.

I don't think that you can do any better with comparisons alone. (By extending the sides, you delimit $25$ rectangular regions in the plane, and it takes $\sim4.64$ bits to number them.)

---

If arithmetic is allowed, the sign of the expression $(x-a)(x-b)$ combines two comparisons in one.